Audit/Search for Unstructured file usage in account
I want to query my full Snowflake account for the use of unstructured files.
Primarily my goal is to understand how our users are using the platform, and what our various teams' use cases are for unstructured data.
I understand that these can be in both internal or external stages, but I'm having trouble finding a nice way to go through our many stages, and list files to check for file types (almost all of them will be csv).
Even a query to look through a single stage to return a list of file types would be helpful, since I could loop through our stages if needed.

Hi - If you want to loop through all your stages and then loop through all the files in each stage then you can do this with a SQL script. If you get stuck then update your question with what you’ve managed to write and ask a question about the issue you’re stuck on
